# Facebook sharing of dynamic php page does not work

Tags: php, facebook, share

I have a slider with images and a link to share the same on FB. The link is to a page called fbshares.php?adid=[dynamic adid]

The fbshares.php page has meta tags whose content is dynamically populated based on the querystring adid value.

You can visit the URL: [Click Here](http://www.ebillboard.net/fbshares.php?adid=3)

When I click on Share button, it does not show the details as well as the image in the share dialog.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebillboard.net%2Ffbshares.php%3Fadid%3D3

Comment: Interesting. Facebook's scraper is getting an "account suspended" page from your host. Contact your host - they may be blocking it. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebillboard.net%2Ffbshares.php%3Fadid%3D3

Comment: You have the `og:url` set to `http://www.ebillboard.net/`, so that is the URL that Facebook will consider the “real” URL for this, and it will try and fetch the meta data from there.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe That helped me sort the issue.